# Reusing old Pallet Instance Number

Tags: runtime

This may come out nonsensical but I'll ask it anyway.

```rust
construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>} = 0,
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>} = 1,
        XcmPallet: pallet_xcm::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>, Origin, Config<T>} = 2,
        TestNotifier: pallet_test_notifier::{Pallet, Call, Event<T>} = 3,
    ...
```

This is the old code, and somehow we don't need `TestNotifier` anymore, so we removed it. After a few months we're adding a new pallet:

```rust
Session: pallet_session::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event, Config<T>} = 3,
```

And to keep it clean, we're reusing the same pallet instance number: ***3***.

Are there repercussions for reusing the same number? Although it's been months long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This affects the call index.

Ensure that there are no scheduled calls before proceeding. And you'd better check if there are any preimage or DApp still using that index.

If not, suppose you schedule a call `0x3::0x0` from democracy, and it will be dispatched after 14 days. This means that the first call of the fourth pallet will be executed at that time. Just make sure it does not accidentally execute your new pallet's call.